# How do I show 404 page for a non existing child page in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Our site is built with WordPress and I notice that our site doesn't redirect non-existing child page routes.

For example I have a page called `about-us` the complete url for that would be `http://example.com/about-us` then if I go to a non-existing child page route of `about-us` which is `http://example.com/about-us/1/` it is showing the contents of its parent `/about-us`

`/about-us/1/` should redirect to a `404` page of WordPress because it's not existing.

I tried the code below in **functions.php** but it only stops auto-guessing urls

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting 404 error on the above?

Comment: @Pratikbhatt nope

Comment: You need to check your .htaccess file as it is not showing you 404

Comment: My .htaccess is in its default configuration.

Comment: Can you share your URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `/(number)/` at the end of an URL, for example in your case `/1/`, WordPress by default parses that as a page parameter. Which is useful for archive pages, but not for single posts and pages.

You can check that yourself by adding this code to the `functions.php` file.

```
  function show_wp_query() {
    global $wp_query;

    echo "<pre>";
    die(var_dump($wp_query)); 
    echo "</pre>";
  }

  add_action('wp', 'show_wp_query');

  -------------------------
  Top section of the output
  -------------------------

  ["query"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["page"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "about-us"
  }
```

But, when you try to access an arbitrary sub-page, you will see that WordPress is actually loading the 404 page. Try this URL - `http://example.com/about-us/sub-page`.

---

**Not-so-good Solution:** However, If you absolutely need to achieve this behavior, I can suggest you what I call a not-so-good solution.

```
  function load_404_page_for_paged_urls() {
    global $wp_query;
    if( !is_single() && !is_page() ) return;

    $page = get_query_var( 'page' );

    if( $page  > 0 ) {
      $wp_query->set_404();
      status_header( 404 );
      get_template_part( 404 );
      exit(); 
    }

  }

  add_action('wp', 'load_404_page_for_paged_urls');
```

Hope this works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Your answer is useful. I might apply your answer to blog part as well

Comment: You're most welcome @ConanCarroll. Also, if you don't mind, can you select the answer as accepted as well? TIA.